# Identifiable but has no consistent estimator

Tags: estimators, consistency, identifiability, estimability

Let $P_\theta$ denote the distribution of the random variable $X$. The distribution depends on the parameter $\theta$ that lies in some parameter space $\Theta$. Consider a function $f(\theta)$ of $\theta$.

We say that $f(\theta)$ is *identifiable* if $f(\theta_1)\neq f(\theta_2)$ implies $P_{\theta_1}\neq P_{\theta_2}$ for every $\theta_1,\theta_2$ in $\Theta$. We say that $f(\theta)$ is *estimable* if $E_\theta g(X)=f(\theta)$ for all $\theta$ in $\Theta$ for some function $g$, where $E_\theta$ denotes the expected value computed from $P_\theta$.

It is easy to show that if $f(\theta)$ is estimable then it is identifiable. One can also find counterexamples where the converse is false. For example, suppose $X$ follows a Bernoulli distribution $P_\theta$ with parameter $\theta=P(X=1)\in(0,1)$, then nonlinear functions of $\theta$ are not estimable.

Can someone provide a simple example where a parameter is identifiable but has no estimator that is consistent for it? In the above example $\sqrt{\theta}$ has a consistent estimator, namely $\sqrt{n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}$ for a random sample $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ from $P_\theta$.

Comment: You have given an inverse definition of identifiability and it corresponds to a tautology, since your description is equivalent to part of the definition of parameter: namely, a parameter has to be a definite property of the distribution.  The remarks about estimability appear to be irrelevant to the question, making them somewhat puzzling.  Please check over your post to verify that it correctly reflects what you want to ask.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your comment I made a few changes to my original post. What do you think now? The definitions are from "Statistical Models: Theory and Practice (Revised Edition)" by David A. Freedman from 2009. I do not see the tautology and in any case this is the question I want to ask. If someone believes the question itself does not make sense, then please do explain.

Comment: I doubt such an error would have appeared in any of Freedman's books, so you might want to re-read your source carefully.

Comment: @whuber On page 125 he writes: "Suppose $P_\theta$ is the probability distribution that governs $X$. The distribution depends on the parameter $\theta$. Think of $X$ as observable, so $P_\theta$ is something we can determine. The function $f(\theta)$ is identifiable if $f(\theta_1)\neq f(\theta_2)$ implies $P_{\theta_1}\neq P_{\theta_2}$ for every pair $(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ of parameter values ... the function $f(\theta)$ is estimable if there is a function $g$ with $E_\theta[g(X)]=f(\theta)$ for all values of $\theta$, where $E_\theta$ stands for the expected value computed from $P_\theta$"

Comment: @whuber Do you want to argue that I misunderstand what is written in the above quote?

Comment: Also, I do not see the "error". The definition seems equivalent to the one on Wikipedia in the "Identifiability" article. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifiability

Comment: Maybe (probably) I am misunderstanding your notation.  The difficulty I run into is that only two concepts are relevant here--distribution $P$ and quantity $f$ (the "estimand")--but your characterization introduces a third parameter.  An estimand is *identifiable* when the association between distribution and estimand is one-to-one.  Any other parameters, like $\theta,$ that might be floating around are irrelevant (and, as I am finding, confusing!). This is relevant because any non-consistent estimator must (therefore) be unable to distinguish two distinct distributions asymptotically.

Comment: There are probably discontinuous examples. Eg with your Bernoulli example, consider $f(x)=x$ for $x<\frac12$, $f(x)=2+x$ for $x>\frac12$, and $f(\frac12)=1$. So $f(\frac12)$ is  not the average of its left-hand and right-hand limits, and I doubt that $f$ has an everywhere-consistent estimator.

Answer (score 2):

Denote the following:

$$\theta\in \Theta= [0,1] \qquad x_1,...,x_n\underset{iid}{\sim}P_\theta(x)$$
$$P_\theta(x)=(1-\theta)\frac{1}{\delta(\theta)}\left(1-\frac{|x-\theta|}{\delta(\theta)}\right)I_{\{ |x-\theta|\le \delta(\theta) \}}+\frac{\theta}{2}I_{\left\{ |x|\le 1 \right\}}$$

where $\delta(\theta)$ is a continuous decreasing function of $\theta$ with $\delta(0)=1$ and $0<\delta(\theta)\le 1-\theta$. For example, we can take $\delta(\theta)=(1-\theta)\exp\left( -(1-\theta)^{-4}+1 \right)$:

[image]

The model is indeed identifiable (it's different for every $\theta$, check and see) and the MLE $\hat{\theta}_n$ exists: The density is positive and continuous in $\Theta$ for any $x$, the log-likelihood function $\ell_n(\theta)=\sum_{m=1}^{n}{\log{P_\theta(x_m)}}$ is continuous and gets a maximum on $[0,1]$.

However, it can be shown (with some effort, going through maximizers and Borell-Cantelli) that the MLE $\hat{\theta}_n$ converges *almost-surely* to 1 for any $\theta_0\in\Theta$, hence the MLE is inconsistent.

Comment: (+1) Thanks! Interesting example. But, in general, that the MLE is inconsistent does not imply that there is no other estimator that is consistent. Maybe my original question is too general.

Comment: You've asked for an example of an identifiable estimator which is inconsistent - there it is. It doesn't imply that all estimators would behave like that, and in general we have to find really pathological cases for such violations of a thumb rule.

Comment: My original question was: "Can someone provide a simple example where a parameter is identifiable but has no estimator that is consistent for it?" I did not specifically ask for an identifiable estimator which is inconsistent. (Of course, if a parameter is identifiable but has no consistent estimator, then any estimator provided will be inconsistent, inclduing the MLE.) If you disagree, then perhaps I don't understand English properly. Nevertheless, I appreciate your answer.